# running java folder/folder/file (wrong name: file) error?

Tags: java

## PROBLEM SOLVED

changed file name to `JavaTT` ...
I guess `JavaTutorial` is a file name you can't use

---

## Original Question

Just started to learn Java.

I created a `JavaTutorial` folder and moved `./Testing/Testing.java` into `JavaTutorial` to get

```
./JavaTutorial/Testing/Testing.java
```

From root directory, I can run

`javac JavaTutorial/Testing/Testing.java` and it creates a `Testing.class` file.

But from here, I try running

`java JavaTutorial/Testing/Testing` and I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
JavaTutorial.Testing.Testing
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
JavaTutorial/Testing/Testing (wrong name: Testing)
```

In my `Testing.java`
I have `package Testing;`

---

If I change `package Testing` to `package Testing.Testing` I get the following error

```
The declared package "Testing.Testing" 
does not match the expected package "Testing"
```

###### What am I doing wrong here??

would appreciate y'alls help on this silly question

---

Complete Code for Testing.java

```
package Testing;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("TESTING");
    }
}
```

is this some weird VSCode glitch/ error?

---

## PROBLEM SOLVED

changed file name to `JavaTT` ...
I guess `JavaTutorial` is a file name you can't use

Comment: How does the `class Testing` look? Could you please post it? Just [edit] your question and include the code of it. Does it have the method `public static void main(String[] args)`?